# Update a photo with python on instagram

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, bots, instagram-api

I am doing a script that publishes photos to Instagram automatically.
I control Instagram web with selenium but when I press the button to update a photo, the file navigator pops-up and I can't still control it with selenium.
[File navigator Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RmGk.png)

I would need to go to my image path(Desktop/bot/img.png) and open it. Is there any library or something that could allow me to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No one can advise you without any information such as html.

As I think you can find <input ... > tag in Instagram HTML.
(please find near upload button.)

If there is it, you can use below sentence.

```
.find_element_by_xpath("(xpath of input tag)").send_keys("(file path)")
```